# Why I can't call same API from Graph Explorer as Powershell executes from Az?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am connecting to `Az` using Powershell:

```
Connect-AzureAd
```

Then, i am trying execute command:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName 'devtest' -ResourceName 'SA-name' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'
```

And eveything work fine, i am getting results. with `-Debug` flag i see, that `Az` executing API method:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/microsoft.graph.getByIds
```

Then, i go to [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and i try to execute the same method from there with the same account that i logged into `Az` and i getting an authorization error from call:

[image]

[When i check, what kind of privilage i need to for perform this action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) i can see that there is no way that my account have `Directory.Read.All` permission granted.

So the question is, why i am allowed to do more actions from `Powershell` tha `graph` using same account?

Answer (score 0):

Pls allow me post it as the answer first for a better desription.

Based on the Error tip on the top of your screenshoot, if you've consent all the permissions in that tab?

By the way, is the azure ad application you used to generate access token in powershell the same as the application for graph explorer? When I decode the access token generated by graph explorer, I found it's generated by app named `Graph explorer (official site)`. I think it may lead to your issue.

[image]
[image]